# How to create a new database from within a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app that has one database per account.  (I know this is a controversial approach in itself, but I'm confident it's the right one in this case.)

I'd like to automate entirely the process of creating a new user account, which means I need to be able create a new database and populate it with some seed data programatically from within a Rails app.

My question, then, is how best to do this?  I don't think I can just run migrations from within the app (or, if I  can, how?), and just running the straight SQL queries within the app with hardcoded CREATE TABLE statements seems a really unwieldy way of doing things.  What approach should I take, then?

Thanks in advance for your help!

David

Comment: I was going to do this and took a lot of flack from the rails community :) Ultimately I decided not to. My plan of attack was that I would dynamically adjust the table name (using set_table_name). Trouble is that since table_name is at the class level, changing the table_name on one instance changes the table_name for all instances. That's as far as I got. I had considered adding a table_name instance variable as opposed to a class variable. Ultimately, it was migrations that scared me off. Curious to see if you come up with anything.

Comment: I'm going with the one-database-per-account method because I don't expect to have that many accounts and some of them can have several million records, so I think it definitely makes sense for me.  I've actually had no trouble thus far in actually running the app.  I just have a before_filter that hijacks the DB connection using establish_connection based on the account subdomain.  Works like a charm -- but I do want a way to run migrations (or the equivalent) so I don't have to create each account manually!

Comment: I'd be interested to know a bit more about why you'd have separate (and a dynamic number of) databases per user account. If you've got a very high level of data and that's why, then you'd probably want to look at a sharding type approach (no dynamic number of tables, but customer accounts are spread across servers). That way your migrations when you *will* change your schema later on are as normal, but done on all your db servers. If your reasoning for multiple db's is for customer separation, or partitioning for convenience, or speed of queries, the reasoning sounds a little more shaky there

Comment: The reason I ask that is because it sounds like (aside from needing to shard for data size) the difficulties in going against the grain on this seem to far outweigh the benefits (perceived or actual) that you might be gaining. You'll end up having every table in your system in each new database right? because otherwise any normal sql functions like joining won't work across more than one database

Comment: Can't speak for @David P but when I was considering a similar solution it was because I would have potentially been dealing with millions of records per user. In my case, I did not require User A to have any visibility to the records of User B. Facebook has actually implemented this (among other things): http://www.quora.com/How-does-Facebook-implement-friend-connections-at-the-database-level - they obviously take it about 10 steps further.

Comment: User accounts are entirely separate -- they don't share data, and they never will.  I don't anticipate having all that many clients (we're talking hundreds or a couple of thousand, not hundreds of thousands or millions).  But each account can have millions of rows.  Each account also has its own Solr index (I suppose I could do this with a single database and a key for each record to indicate the account, but performance becomes a real issue here).  Dealing with multiple servers also becomes easier this way, and in some cases I may give high-volume clients their own servers.

Comment: This isn't to say that I couldn't handle all of these issues using one database, but I think in this case the challenges I'm dealing with are worth it for the advantages of multiple databases.  And, just to be clear, every database will be identical in structure (i.e. there's no dynamic number of tables -- everybody should run from the same schema).  There's actually a second database of accounts that everybody's linked to, but I haven't had any issues there.  Interestingly enough, despite all the concerns I've read about using my approach, this is really the only major issue I've run into!

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that my application requires. The app provides a web front-end onto a number of remote embedded devices which in turn monitor sensors. Each embedded device runs a ruby client process which reads a config file to determine its setup. There is a need to be able to add a new sensor type.

The approach I have is that each sensor type has it's own data table, which is written into by every device which has that sensor. So in order to be able to create a new sensor type, I need to be able to set up new tables.

One initial issue is that the remote embedded devices do not have a rails app on them - therefore table name pluralization is a bad plan, as the pluralization rules are not accessible to the remote devices. Therefore I set

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

in config/environment.rb

The data on each sensor device type is held in a SensorType model - which has two fields - the sensor name, and the config file contents.

Within the SensorType model class, there are methods for:

1. Parsing the config file to extract field names and types
2. Creating a migration to build a new model
3. Altering a particular field in the DB from a generic string to char(17) as it is a MAC address used for indexing
4. Altering the new model code to add appropriate belongs_to relationships
5. Build partial templates for listing the data in the table (a header partial and a line_item partial)

These methods are all bound together by a create_sensor_table method which calls all the above, and performs the appropriate require or load statements to ensure the new model is immediately loaded. This is called from the create method in the SensorTypeController as follows:

```
  # POST /device_types
  # POST /device_types.xml
  def create
    @sensor_type = SensorType.new(params[:sensor_type])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sensor_type.save

        @sensor_type.create_sensor_tables

        flash[:notice] = 'SensorType was successfully created.'
        #etc
```